# How to: get_user_meta - BuddyPress

Tags: buddypress, meta-query, user-meta

What is the proper way to display User Meta in the BP Loop using this line from codex?

```
 <?php get_user_meta($user_id, $key, $single);  ?>
```

I added that line to the profile loop and switched those values with ones from my DB and nothing happened. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php 
  $user_id = 9;
  $key = 'last_name';
  $single = true;
  $user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 
  echo '<p>The '. $key . ' value for user id ' . $user_id . ' is: ' . $user_last . '</p>'; 
?>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted, do you mean you want a dynamic way to get the user id? maybe the displayed member id?

Comment: No Ahmad. I wanted to retrieve something from the database. The guys in the chat have actually given me the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the loop, you can get the currently iterated user id using `bp_get_member_user_id()`.

Also, it's best practice to use `bp_get_user_meta()`, because it works better with certain kinds of BP plugins (multi-network, etc).

Thus:

```
if ( bp_has_members() ) {
    while ( bp_members() ) {
        bp_the_member();
        $user_last = bp_get_user_meta( bp_get_member_user_id(), 'last_name', true );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly me. I forgot to replace this line

```
$user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single );
```

with actual values

```
$user_last = get_user_meta( 1, nickname, true );
```